# How to send headers conditionally in workbox service worker

Tags: reactjs, progressive-web-apps, vite, workbox

I have a vite react pwa (Client side rendering).
I have a special route that is cross-site-isolated as this route uses SharedArrayBuffer.
For this reason, I excluded index.html or / from precache so that the app can work.
So it's not a true PWA.

What I want to do is.

1. Include index.html or / in precache
2. But when the page is requested, I want to check whether is it that route that requires site isolation headers or not. If it requires, then I augment the response in the service worker before returning the response.

How can I achieve this in workbox?